# Error fromulario Angular - Observable - Servicio Envio de Mail - Type 'Observable<Object>' is missing the following properties

Tags: angular, formularios, observable, angular2-template

edite la pregunta, porque genere un nuevo proyecto angular  y copie este codigo para enviar el formulario.
Los errores que me da son 4

ngForm
Error: contact/contact.component.ts:48:38 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'NgForm'.

48 getSentServices(body:ContactForm, f: NgForm){

no me deja declarar el componente app-contacta en App Module ni en app.component
Error: app.module.ts:10:5 - error NG6001: The class 'ContactComponent' is listed in the declarations of the NgModule 'AppModule', but is not a directive, a component, or a pipe. Either remove it from the NgModule's declarations, or add an appropriate Angular decorator.

10     ContactComponent
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

contact/contact.component.ts:31:14
31 export class ContactComponent implements OnInit {
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
'ContactComponent' is declared here.

y con matsnackbar

contact/contact.component.ts:39:72
39   constructor(private sendServices: SendEmailService, public snackBar: MatSnackBar) { }
~~~~~~~~~~~
This type does not have a value, so it cannot be used as injection token.

contact/contact.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
//componentes de form
import {FormControl, NgForm, Validators} from     '@angular/forms';
//modelo creado
import {ContactForm} from '../models/contactForm';
//services en angular
   import {SendEmailService} from '../services/send-email.service';
//libreria rxjs

//libreria rxjs
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { of } from 'rxjs';



//material desing de angular
import {MatSnackBar} from '@angular/material/snack-bar';



@Component({
 selector: 'app-contact',
 templateUrl: './contact.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./contact.component.css']

  })
     export class ContactComponent implements     OnInit {
 //creacion de variable contact
  ContactModel = new ContactForm();
  private emailResponse: any;
  private truefalse:boolean = false;

 constructor(private sendServices:     SendEmailService, public snackBar:    MatSnackBar) { }

  ngOnInit() {
}

onSubmit(f: NgForm){
this.getSentServices(this.ContactModel, f);
}
     //metodo de services
   getSentServices(body:ContactForm, f: NgForm){
      this.sendServices.getResponseEmail(body).subscribe(
       data => {
        if(data){
            this.snackBar.open("Gracias por el mensaje", "Correcto", {
                duration: 2000,
              });
              f.reset();
        }
        else{
             this.snackBar.open(":(", "Error", {
                duration: 2000,
              });
              
        }
        
     },
      err => { this.snackBar.open("Algo fallo :/, correo: cesar@unprogramador.com", "ups", {
           duration: 5000,
         }); }
     );

   }

  }
```

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ContactComponent } from './contact/contact.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
   ContactComponent --me la rechaza--
 ],
 imports: [
   BrowserModule,
   FormsModule
],

 providers: [],
 bootstrap: [AppComponent],

 })
   export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: decis luego de corregirlo que corregiste exactamente?

Comment: es porque luego decís que te da otros errores pero no decís cuales,.En   getResponseEmail recibis datos que te da console.log(type)?...json_decode()cuando es true los objects JSON devueltos serán convertidos a array asociativos que me parece por no ver lo anterior que es lo que se requiere

Comment: Hola, errores con   ([ngModel]) que lo puse asi y estaba [(ngModel)]  me daba error. El componente del formulario no me lo reconocio nunca. y ahora tengo un conflicto con router-outlet , y voy a clonar el repositorio otra vez , y empezar otra vez con esto. Me fije recien y en contact.component.ts en la primera linea me da error #contactForm="ngForm" > No directive found with exportAs 'ngForm'.ngtsc(-998003) .   Borre una linea que de donde lo saque decia que la podia borrar, de Ngform. directivas en contact.component.ts  . Edito y te remarco la pregunta. Lo intentare de nuevo,

Comment: Edite la pregunta, cree un nuevo proyecto e inclui solamente los componentes para el formulario.

Answer (score 0):

el problema estaba en el componente. contact.component
Cree otro componente y se terminaron eos errores.
De todos modos no lo puedo ver.
voy a hacer otra pregunta para eso. gracias